# Keyboard resignfirstresponder when Click Done

Tags: objective-c, ibaction

I have a textfield called `searchBox` and am trying to get rid of the keyboard if the user either clicks on Done.

Is there an IBAction that I need to know to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make your viewcontroller an UITextFieldDelegate and write in

```
viewDidLoad:
[searchBox setDelegate:self];
```

And then write:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textfield
{
    [searchbox resignFirstResponter];
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Why do I need to make it a delegate?

Comment: Because otherwise it doesn't call textFieldShouldReturn method

Answer (score 2):

In your view controller:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // ...
    searchBox.delegate = self;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField
{
    [searchBox resignFirstResponder];

    return YES;
}
```

See the [UITextFieldDelegate documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITextFieldDelegate/textFieldShouldReturn%3a) for details (you might want to return NO instead of YES in my example).